# Angularjs how to activate ng-click inside ng-bind-html-unsafe?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following scenario:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
        <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="phone.snippet"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.phone = {"name": "Nexus S","snippet": '<div ng-click="click()">test</div>'};
    $scope.click = function () {
        alert();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29JKZ/

Currently whenever I click on the test div nothing will happen although the `ng-click="click()"` is defined.
So how can I enable angular to listen to the `ng-click` event originating in the `ng-bind-html-unsafe`?

I've tried with `ng-bind-html` too but I'm seeing the same behavior

Note that I'm using angularjs **v1.0.7**, and upgrading it to a more recent version is not possible.

Thanks

Comment: using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is too late to use angular directives.  You need it to be compiled and linked to work.

Comment: Is there a way of creating html code, including angular js directives, at the javascript level and then push it into the DOM and have angular JS handle it?